# Why did this MOSFET blow up?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, batteries, nmos, pmos

I have a DC drill with adjustable speed. I would like to add a battery protection circuit which shut-downs the motor if the battery voltage is too low. I would like to use the built-in slide switch which sets the speed in the different positions. When the switch is at "0" state, the switch grounds the terminals.

I made the following circuit but my problem is the lower 2N7002 blows-up. I tested more times and sometimes the TPC8107 FET short circuited too.

Could you help me what can be the problem? I would like to use the slide switch to shutdown the whole circuit.

EDIT:

Yes, the IRFZ48N gate driver is missing on the schematic, I didn't draw it, it is a PIC that belongs to the drill.

Yes, LM358 is incomplete.

It is just a sample, but the MOSFET circuit is complete and the real circuit that I made.

Drill max current is 6A.

[image]

New image:
[image]

Comment: Your circuit is incomplete, there is no gat drive for the output FET.

Comment: Also check that you have the 2n7002 pinout is correct and for short circuits. As the circuit is, it wouldn't work but shouldn't blow the FET either.

Comment: Your battery voltage comparator scares me, suppose the LM358 isn't initialized properly for whatever reason and it makes its output high, then it can never "get back". Then your battery detection basically does nothing anymore. I would make that a "Schmitt trigger" circuit by removing the 1N4001 and replacing it with a resistor.

Comment: Have you checked whether there's a short between gate and source (or drain) of your TPC8107? (Also, the TPC8107 can't handle enough current for a drill.)

Comment: Are you sure the drill uses a PIC? Not that it matters, but I would have expected some no-name microcontroller.

Comment: Yes this certainly looks like a self destruct circuit between 12V and B+

Comment: What happens if you put some resistances (eg. 10k) in series with the 2N7002 Gate and Drain leads to limit current surges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Could you help me what can be the problem?*

[image]

As the battery voltage (at 12 volts) drops, you reach a point where the 2N7002 starts to shut-down a little. This in turn starts to shut-down the TPC8107 series-pass MOSFET. But, the load is still taking several amps to power the drill motor.

So, what happens now is that the TPC8107 starts to dissipate a lot of heat; several amps are still flowing from source to drain but, the drain source voltage has increased due to it shutting down. As it shuts down more, the load current will drop but, the drain source resistance will increase and you'll reach a point where the MOSFET internal junction rises massively above the rated temperature (150°C to 175°C) and the internals melt down and fail.

This can often cause a short between source and gate and now the shutting-down 2N7002 is subject to several hundred milliamps at maybe 50 to 10 volts and it also melts down. This can all happen in a fraction of 1 millisecond.

So, due to the speed at which this happens to the TP8107 it may not actually feel very warm at all but, once that device melts gate and source, you'll see the 2N7002 fry and maybe disappear in smoke. So, you change the 2N7002 and the next one burns too. This happens because you are not aware that the TP8107 is internally shorting its pins.

It's a well-known phenomenon in MOSFETs - as soon as you start to control them in a linear fashion, you need to jump through hoops circuit-wise in order to protect them.

The trick is to apply hysteresis - as soon as the 2N7002 starts to shut-down, you enforce a hard-shut-down so that the series-pass MOSFET never operates in its linear region. Of course this can result in a type of PWM action that causes the motor to judder and splutter so, the next cause of action is to enforce a non-retriggerable event stop that is manually reset.

If you are clever, you can apply a timed turn-off event that restarts automatically after 1 second (or 10 seconds etc.).

Comment: Hi Andy, 
Thank you for the detailed answer. I tested the circuit more, and it looks like only the 2N7002 MOSFET burns, the TPC8107 operates well. There was only 1 time when the TPC8107 shorted but I think it was my fault due to soldering error. If I start the circuit without the motor its working fine, I tested it with a bulb, worked well and the 2N7002 didn't burned. But when I connected the motor the 2N7002 instantly died with a little explosion. Maybe should I change it to a lower RDS(on) MOSFET or will that burns instantly again?

Comment: Your observations may be valid but so are mine. Irrespective of what you observe and report, the basic problem with your circuit is that it will burn MOSFETs.

Comment: What about if only the TPC8107 would be in the circuit? Would it also burn? 
Or the circuit would be the same but I can take an NTC in series with the motor so the voltage drop on the battery can be smaller. Can also burn the MOSFETs in this case?

Comment: The devil is in the detail and I can't see your detail.

Comment: Edited my question. For example with a 10R NTC in series with the motor can limit inrush current so voltage drop on the battery would be smaller and the MOSFET gate voltage wouldn't go below the treshold. What's more, if the motor has already started I can short it with an other mosfet. What do you think?

Comment: I think you need to make a circuit like how I described and stop messing around trying to polish a turd. OK, you might get lucky but, in my experience, do the job once; do the job right.